# My real ads do not appear in my application, only the test ads

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-chrome, admob

Good afternoon, I'm making an app and I'm setting up a part of the ad using google admob, but when I put my AD ID it doesn't appear in my app, it only appears with the test ID. I'm using an emulator to use android. And my AD units were created a long time ago. Do I need to publish my app to the play store for ads to appear? Or is my code wrong?

//AndroidManifest.xml Code

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-4462240214744405~5342560161" />
```

// Java Code

```
   private AdRequest mAdRequest;
   private AdView mAdView;


    //AD LOADING

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
    }
      });

     //AD
    mAdView =findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(mAdRequest);
```

//Layout Code

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
   android:id="@+id/adView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   app:adSize="BANNER"
   app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4462240214744405/1315856688"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Why are you using two different application ids in your admob?

Comment: Where? You are talking about android:id or adUnitId?

Comment: I see two admob ids in your code and the manifest.

Comment: Beacuse in the manifest i put APP ID that finds in Admob, and in my code is the banner adUnitId

Comment: The AdMob ads will not show during the debug mode, if your app is not published yet on Google Play, the ads will appear when you publish it on Google Play, if you make an update to your existed app, you need to test your app in release mode

Comment: Oh, thanks, i didn't now. i gonna try